# Write a String into a custom file format

Tags: java, string

I need to write a Java String to a file. But content of this file should not be able to read with a text editor. I can't encrypt the file either but I can use any other conversions like convert to a bits and write to file. I found several methods but in all the methods, the content can be able to read with a text editor. Is there any method to achieve this task.

Edit-
If this file opened with Notepad++, content should show like this.

[image]

Comment: You wrote in your question: _not be able to read with a text editor_ This is not clear to me. Do you mean the file should not be a text file? Or do you mean that it should be a text file but its contents should not be understandable when the file is opened in a text editor?

Comment: @Abra This file should not be a text file. Even if you open this file with a text editor like Notepad++ it should not show alpha numerical character. I tried several examples like covert String in to bytes[] and write byte[] to a file but you can see the exact content with some none alpha numerical characters. For example if you open with Notepad++ it should show content like this "PK     ! ‡Vá2†  ™   "

Comment: This is just a compressed file, probably zip.

Comment: @1438886 What exactly do you want to achieve? And why?

Comment: @MCEmperor In my application, I want store a encryption key in a file and read it later. My solution is to write the key in a custom format which will not be plain text and it will not be able to read with any text editor. I took this screen shot by opening a Excel (.xsls) in Notepad++.

Comment: But this is not encryption, this is *compression*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could encrypt the String in your program. Just replace every char with a certain other char. And then write the new String in the File. When you read the file after: just decrypt the String again in your program.

Comment: This is a good solution. I edited the question to be more clear. I wanted to go to a different direction. But definitely this will be my plan B

Answer (score 0):

Treat the String as an Object.

Use `ObjectOutputStream()` to write String to file.

See :
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/fileoutputstream/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

```java
String s = "To be written";
ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(path));
objectOut.writeObject(s);
objectOut.close();
```